# In views, show the number of users who have subscribed to the organic group

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am using the following modules
1. [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)
2. [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

A content type called **Course** has been created. It has been set as an organic group.
It has group members(Users who have subscribed to the course).

I have created a view which shows the list of all the groups (Nodes of type Course).
In another column, I want to show the number of users who have subscribed to the group(course).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the OG membership ID:s to start with.

1. Add new view. Show -> OG membership (important!)
2. Then in some display add a contextual filter -> OG membership: Entity id.
3. Provide default value -> Type -> User ID from logged in user.
4. Override title: %1's groups. Specify validation criteria -> User.

Now you have the list of ID's.

5. Next to get the actual titles of the groups (as the base table is OG membership, not node), Add a relationship -> Group Node from OG membership.
6. Add a field -> Content: Title. Relationship -> Group node from OG membership.

Now you get the titles too. For test add some filters and sort criteria.

Comment: i already have the list of courses. i just want the  number of members   subscribed to that course.  
Its like :  

Courses     Members  

Course1    10  
Course2     7